# BASH loop through folders and files

Tags: linux, bash

I have a problem with listing through directories. I wanted to make script which will loop through dirs and files in them so I can move them elsewhere.

My problem is that I need to SORT all the files within the folders. There's like 2000 directories and I need to loop through them and then loop through all files within these dirs and sort them by extension in directory which will be created (or files will be moved) and it's name will be that particular extension

Could anyone help?

```
#!/bin/bash

tar_fol="$HOME/Desktop/try/"
to_fol="$HOME/Desktop/SortedFiles/"

for DIRE in "$(ls -d  $tar_fol"*")"
do

  echo "Checking dir : $DIRE"

  for FIL in "$(ls -p $tar_fol$DIRE)"
  do
    echo "Checking file : $FIL"

    if [ "$(find ~/Desktop/ -type d -name ${FIL##*.})" != "" ]
      then
          mv -f $tar_fol$FIL $to_fol${FIL##*.}
      else
        mkdir $to_fol${FIL##*.}
        mv $tar_fol$FIL $to_fol${FIL##*.}
      fi

  done
done
```

Comment: Apart from `$FILE` (line 17) which maybe changed to `$FIL`, can you describe better the problem you're having (if your script is not working)?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. My problem is that I need to SORT all the files within the folders. There's like 2000 directories and I need to loop through them and then loop through all files within these dirs and sort them by extension in directory which will be created (or files will be moved) and it's name will be that particular extension

Problem is that '6 for DIRE in `"$(ls -d  $tar_fol"*")" ` giving me an error

Comment: Please provide a sample of the directory structure used as input and the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quoting the wildcard, so you are looking for files whose name *literally* ends with the character `*`.

Anyway, [you should not use `ls` to drive loops](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and also, you should avoid using uppercase for your private variables.

```
#!/bin/bash

tar_fol="$HOME/Desktop/try/"
to_fol="$HOME/Desktop/SortedFiles/"

for dire in "$tar_fol"/*/.
do
  echo "Checking dir: '$dire'"
  for fil in "$dire"/*
  do
    echo "Checking file: '$fil'"
    find ~/Desktop/ -type d -name "${fil##*.}" -exec sh -c 'mkdir -p "$0";
        mv "$@" "$0"' "$to_fol" "$fil" {} \+
  done
done
```

I'm not sure I understand exactly what the innermost loop is supposed to accomplish, so there is some guesswork there.  The general idea is to pass the destination directory in `$0` (obscure hack, but it's fairly common) and the found files to the `-exec` script.

Comment: First loop is for looping through folders and second for looping through files within these folders. Anyway thanks for your reply.

Btw: `find: missing argument to -exec'  `

Comment: Sorry about that; added the `{}` which I guess is what it was complaining about.  If your `find` doesn't support `-exec ... {} \+` some additional refactoring is required.  My question is about the innermost loop -- the one I replaced with just a `find`.

Comment: that loop is for listing through files in folder so if the file has extension for example .txt then, if directory with the same name as extension of the file exists in `to_fol` move that file there, if not then make new dir in `to_fol` with a name of it's extension (of file which was listed in for loop) and move that file to that folder

Comment: basically my problem is that i need to sort all of the files from my RECOVERY of SSD. It's about 1500 folders by 500 files. I need to sort every type of file by it's extension to separate folder

Comment: So then maybe `find ~/Desktop -type f -name "*.${fil##*.}" -exec sh -c 'mkdir -p "$@"; mv "$@" "$0"' "$to_fol/${fil##*.}" {} \+` but I guess this is going to do the same extension many times, so you should optimize away those cases (pipe through `sort -u`? Skip if the directory in `$to_fol` already exists?)

Comment: Now the problem is `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘Checking file: '/home/xarz/Desktop/try//recup_dir.2/./t27443200.jpg'’
: File exists` there are `//` and that's a big problem... But I will try to fix it, anyway thanks for help and it should work now...

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `ls` command

```
cd $HOME/Desktop/try/
ls -laRX
```

OR

```
ls -laRX $HOME/Desktop/try/

   -l     use a long listing format
   -a, --all do not ignore entries starting with .
   -R, --recursive
          list subdirectories recursively
   -X     sort alphabetically by entry extension
```

Refer `man ls` for more information

Comment: Neat, I had never heard of `-X`, there's really a tool for everything !